# Support Fragment custom animations ignoring interpolator

Tags: android, animation, fragment, android-support-library

The interpolator is completely getting ignored in my framgne animations. Is this a known bug or am I missing something?

transaction:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_top, R.anim.hold, R.anim.hold, R.anim.slide_out_to_top)
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment, TAG)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

slide_out_to_top animation (the other one is essentiall the same)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0"
               android:toYDelta="-100%p"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer my own here. Seems the problem is that the interpolator needs to be on the outermost node. I can solve my problem by simply removing the "set" wrapper. If you have a set, you can likely move the interpolator to the outermost level to fix this.